# Event Class C# linking form with another class

Tags: c#, forms, class, events

I need to cause an event in my Form 1 class to pull the text from an instance varible in an array from another class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {


        Game game;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

public void StartNewGame()
        {

            game = new Game(this);
        }



    public void DisplayName(string name)
            {

                PlayerLabel.Text = "Player1"; 
            }
```

This is the event handler in Form1 that when clicked will start a new game. This is also where I would like the PlayerName.Text to be set. the name of the player on screen

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartNewGame();
        }
```

And the Game class:

```
class Game
{

    private Player[] players = new Player[2];
    private int currentPlayerIndex = 0;
    private Player currentPlayer;
    private int playersFinished = 0;
    private Form1 form;



    public Game(Form1 form) {

        this.form = form;

        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++){
            players[i] = new Player("players" + i + 1);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raising an event inside a class and use an handler on another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421907/raising-an-event-inside-a-class-and-use-an-handler-on-another-class)

Comment: All the properties in the Game class are private and you don't have any public methods to return the values.  The class Game is also not public.

Comment: its not a duplicate @raidensan

Comment: In a nutshell, you are asking for **Raising an event inside a class and use it on another class** (Main form is a _class_). So, yes. It is a duplicate. You can't expect SO users to address your issue when a _very similar_ issue is already solved by an answer. Please review the answer and try to implement that logic into your code.

Comment: I DON'T UNDERSTAND IT @raidensan don't be so negative

Comment: I've reported you @raidensan expect your account to be deleted soon...